# Two parallel div having asynchronous scrolling issue in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, scroll

I have created two parallel div having same content, and placed in parallel

Now, I have captured the scroll event on right hand side div and scroll the left hand side `div`. On Chrome and Firefox, both `div` are scrolling synchronously.

But on IE11, there is a small lag in left hand side `div`, which I can see easily.

```js
$('#bottom').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#top').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
div {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    width    : 50%;
    height   : 300px;
}

div p{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#top {
    overflow : hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    left     : 0;
}
#bottom {
    left     : 50%;
    overflow : scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>10th P Tag</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>20th P Tag</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>30th P Tag</p>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>10th P Tag</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>20th P Tag</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>30th P Tag</p>
</div>
```

Created a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/sanketbajoria/2uvsc9c3/

Actually, above issue is a bigger problem in ExtJS library, where locked and normal grid scroll in above manner.

Can anyone please help me with it? I'm stuck with it.

Comment: I couldn't seem to replicate the issue with IE11 on Win10

Comment: oh, i am using IE11 on Win 7. I don't think that would be a problem.